# Six x’s has to be placed in the squares in the adjacent figure, such that each row contains at least one x. This can be done in

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

[image]

Question is -

> Six x’s has to be placed in the squares in the adjacent figure, such
>   that each row contains at least one x. This can be done in how many ways?

Due to the limit on the number of x's, I find this question very diffiult to solve.

I tried representing the figure as $$_,_|_,_,_,_|_,_$$

And 3 x's are already use for each row and we are left with 3 more x's

but I'm unable to proceed further. How to tackle such problems?

Comment: Since you have to put six x's, you can ask yourself in how many ways you can color two squares such that no row is fully colored.

Comment: @Marc I think that this is not correct. You can fully occupy row 1, 2, 3 and still have an $x$ in every row.

Comment: @Stef the colored squares are the empty ones.

Comment: @JacobRaihle Oh, yes, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's count cases based on how many cells of the middle row are occupied

1. All $4$ cells. Then you have $2$ remaining $x$'s and you should put $1$ in the first row ($2$ options) and $1$ in the third row (another $2$ options). So $$2\times 2=4$$ ways.
2. $3$ cells. You can occupy $3$ cells in $\dbinom{4}{3}=4$ ways. This leaves you with $3$ more $x$'s. Choose now a row from rows $1$ and $3$ ($2$ ways to do that), put $2$ of the $x$'s in that row and put the last $x$ in the remaining row ($2$ cells to choose from). So $$4\times 2 \times 2=16$$ ways.
3. $2$ cells. You can occupy $2$ cells in $\dbinom{4}{2}=6$ ways. This leaves you with $4$ more $x$'s and no other choice but to place them in the remaining cells. So $$6\times 1=6$$ ways.

If you occupy less than $2$ cells in the middle row, then there is not enough space for the remaining $x$'s, so that was all. Summing up $$4+16+6=26$$ ways.

Answer (score 24):

Only the top or bottom row can be left blank in $1$ way each,

thus ways with at least one  $x$ in each row = $\binom86 -2 = 26$

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I find it difficult understanding the subtraction of 2

Comment: We have $8$ squares, but only $6 x's$, so $2$ squares will always be left blank. There are $\binom86$ total ways of placing the $x's$, but if the blank squares are either **both** in the top row or **both** in the bottom row, the given stipulation is not met, so we subtract $2$.

Comment: Alternatively, you may consider placing $2$ **blanks** in the squares so that no row is left totally blank. $\binom82 -2$ ( the same cases mentioned above).

Answer (score 9):

See there are $8$ places to be filled but even though if we fill only the rows then also $2$ places would aleays remain. So to arrange 6 letters among 8 places its simply ${8\choose 6}-2=26$ .$-2$ as two of the top or bottom  places would never be filled howsoever we place $x$ hope its clear.

Comment: Interesting, this is altogether a very different approach for me. I usually understand the approach that @Stef used in his answer below, but yours might help in competitive exams

Comment: Thanks ! Hope you liked it.

Comment: "as two places would never be filled.." doesn't explain why $2$ should be subtracted, since there are many ways two places can remain unfilled.

Comment: Total letters are to be filled in $8$ squares thats what i want to say.

Comment: "Total letters are to be filled in $8$ squares.." is right, but $2$ squares never being filled does not explain subtracting $2$.

Comment: okay i got it .

Comment: I am afraid that "two of the top or bottom places would never be filled howsoever we place $x$" is also not correct. Either **both** of the top row or **both** of the bottom row unfilled is the reason for subtracting $2$. See also the comment by Marc and Jacob against the question.

Comment: plz can you explain

Comment: "two of the top or bottom places would never be filled howsoever we place $x$" includes cases where $1$ at the top and $1$ at the bottom remains unfilled.

Comment: i got it now thanks

Answer (score 3):

If $n_i$ denotes the number of x's in row $i$ diminished by $1$ then $n_1+n_2+n_3=3$ where $n_1,n_3\in\{0,1\}$ and $n_2\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. Discern the following cases:

- $0+3+0$ gives $\binom21\binom44\binom21=4$ possibilities.
- $1+2+0$ gives $\binom22\binom43\binom21=8$ possibilities.
- $0+2+1$ gives $\binom21\binom43\binom20=8$ possibilities.
- $1+1+1$ gives $\binom22\binom42\binom22=6$ possibilities.
  $4+8+8+6 =26$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach via generating functions.  Consider the more general problem of placing $r$ x's in the figure.  Let $a_r$ be the number of ways this can be done, subject to the constraint of having at least one x in each row.  Then the generating function for $\{a_r\}$ is
$$f(x) = [(1+x)^2-1]^2 \cdot [(1+x)^4-1] = x^8+8 x^7+26 x^6+44 x^5+40 x^4+16 x^3$$

The answer to the original problem is the coefficient of $x^6$, i.e. $26$.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you come up with this generating function for arranging the $X's$, I have just started learning about generating functions.

Comment: @user350331, consider the row with 4 squares.  We could place 1 x in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways, 2 x's in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, 3 x's in $\binom{4}{3}$   ways, or 4 x's in $\binom{4}{4}$ ways.  So the GF for ways to place x's in that row is $4 x + 6 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4 = (1+x)^4 -1$.  Similarly for the rows with 2 squares, each has GF $(1+x)^2-1$.  Multiply these GFs together to get the GF for the total figure.  You might like to read http://people.math.sfu.ca/~alspach/mag82/

Answer (score 1):

If the bottom row only has a left x, then there are 5 more x's to distribute among the top two rows. We are then essentially choosing which box does not have an x (as there are 6 boxes), and any such choice is valid, so there are 6 choices. The same count holds when the bottom row only has a right x. Now we consider when both bottom boxes have an x. Say then the top row only has a left x. Then there are 3 remaining x's to go to the middle row, so there are 4 many options. The same for the top row only having a right x. The last situation is when the top row is filled, and there are 2 x's to distribute in the middle row. There are 6, 4 choose 2, many options.

6+6+4+4+6 = 26.